# Where should I put .xnb files in mono game project using VS2010?

Tags: xna, monogame

My problem was described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/bobfamiliar/windows-8-xna-and-monogame-part-3-getting-windows-8-store-ready) in the "The Content Pipeline" paragraph.

The author describes how to fix it using VS2012: put xnb files to \AppX\Content folder but I use VS2010 and mono game templates for it and there is no folder like this, so where must I put these assets to run the game correctly?

Answer (score 1):

AppX exists only in Windows 8 Store app (which is impossible to build on VS2010) You should place your Content folder in .exe location, usually bin/Debug, or just add it to the project with options "Content" and "Copy if newer/always".

Answer (score 0):

Build the project.

Now the AppX folder should exist in "bin/Debug/"

Create the content folder and put your files in it.

Here's the tutorial I used for [VS2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devfish/archive/2012/09/15/how-to-create-your-first-xna-monogame-framework-application-for-windows-8-metro-ported.aspx) a while ago.

Comment: i dont have any AppX folder in bin/Debug/ againts that i have "name.vshost" file